# Incremental rendering with React

Tags: reactjs

I need to render a very large table (thousands of rows/columns). For various reasons I cannot use virtualization which is what I otherwise would resort to. I also cannot paginate. The user gets the whole table or nothing.

To improve perceived performance, is it possible to have React render the table in increments? E.g:

1. Render the container with scrollbars.
2. Render empty cells
3. Render cell content
4. Etc.

The above steps could of course be more fine-grained. The point is that the user should be able to see them as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). It's designed to handle hundreds of thousands of rows in a performant manner.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a viable solution since it is neither React nor actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say: serve it in chunks and fix the server, not the cient. But if this is not possible in your case...

Maybe you can load all the data in a object/array and return it in chunks? For example on the initial page load request all the data and return the first 100 items. React can render this in a table like you normally do. When the users click on a "load" button (scrolls to the end of the page, etc...), load the next 100 items. The browser won't crash during render.

If you want to search in the data, you definitely wanna use some sort of algorithm like Binary Tree Search. Just iterate a large data set is very time expensive...